# Merge two datasets in R without a key variable

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I have two datasets that have to be merged in R, though I have no idea how this can be conducted:

1) One dataset has 400 rows; each row has one cell is filled with 635 0 and 1's.

V1 "0,1,0,0,0,0,0,..."

V2 "0,0,0,0,0,1,0,..."

V3 "1,0,0,1,0,0,0,..."

etc.

This dataset has to be matched to the second dataset to find out what the 1 means:

2) This dataset has one row with 635 columns

V1 A,B,C,D,E,F,G,...

So I want that the 1 in V1 of the first dataset is connected to the B of the second dataset.

Anyone ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by match? The second dataset should become the column names of the first dataset?

Comment: I think you mean cbind (bind columns).

Comment: I want to retrieve: 
V1 "B"
V2 "F"
V3 "A", "D"

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but here is an attempt to answer your question:

```
#create sample data
  V1<- "0,1,0,0,0,0,0"
  V2<- "0,0,0,0,0,1,0"
  V3<-"1,0,0,1,0,0,0"
  df<-data.frame( col1=rbind(V1, V2, V3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  letters<-"A,B,C,D,E,F,G"

#split the character string into individual elements
  letters<-unlist(strsplit(letters, ","))

#split the 0,1 string into columns, make dataframe
  incol<-sapply(df$col1, function(x) {unlist(strsplit(x, ","))})
  dfsep<-as.data.frame(incol, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#rename rows and columns
names(dfsep)<-rownames(df)
rownames(dfsep)<-letters

#desired answer
#V1 "B" V2 "F" V3 "A", "D"
#examine each column and find the rows with a 1
#answer as list
 answer<-sapply(dfsep, function(x){letters[as.integer(x)==1]})

#answer as vector
 answer2<-sapply(dfsep, function(x){toString(letters[as.integer(x)==1])})
```

Depending on your analysis I left the final answer either as list or a vector.  Good luck.